# Test to see if a string is an XML document or not in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a string that may or may not contain valid xml content. How can I test to see if that particular string is a valid xml document or not? I would prefer this to be in jQuery or just plain javascript.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to check for XML if it is well formed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752492/regex-to-check-for-xml-if-it-is-well-formed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this JQuery code:

```
function isXML(xml){
    try {
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); //is valid XML
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        // was not XML
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This always returns false because of 'ReferenceError: xmlDoc is not defined'. declaring "var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)" works fine.